# Spring/Hibernate handling of SQL Exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working with an external company who have developed an application for us using Spring/Hibernate.
I have been troubleshooting an issue with them where we were getting the following exception logged:

```
 org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: could not execute query; 
   uncategorized SQLException for SQL [call preNotifySynctopda(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; 
   Cursor is closed.; 
   nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cursor is closed. java.sql.SQLException: Cursor is closed exception
```

Working with them to identify root cause of the problem, and they have identified that root cause of problem is that SQL Exception `NO_DATA_FOUND` is being thrown from the stored procedure.
Relevant code is the following:

```
public List<Sync> getPreNotifyserversync(final String userid, final String countrycode, 
        final String servrtable, final int noOfRec) {
  return (List<Sync>) hibernateTemplate.execute(new HibernateCallback() {
    public Object doInHibernate(final Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
      Query q = session.getNamedQuery("preNotifySynctopda"); //
      q.setParameter("vUserid", userid); //
      q.setParameter("vCountrycode", countrycode);
      q.setParameter("vServrtable", servrtable);
      q.setParameter("vNoofrec", noOfRec);
      return q.list();
    }
  });
}
```

What I am trying to understand is how the exception is getting transformed from `NO_DATA_FOUND` to `CURSOR IS CLOSED`.
My supicion from looking at the code above, is that `getPreNotifyserversync` seems to swallowing the `SQLException thrown by doInHibernate`.
The returned resultset is then acted on, even though it is not valid (never initiated to to thrown exception).
Note I am particularly experienced in Spring/Hibernate, so not sure how these kind of exceptions should be handled.
What I would ensure is that the actual original exception (NO_DATA_FOUND) is somehow logged.  Is this possible?

For reference, here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UAT_RW.preNotifySynctopda(my_refcur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, vUserid IN f_synctopda.user_id%type, vCountrycode IN f_synctopda.country_cd%type, vServrtable IN f_synctopda.servrtable%type, vNoOfRec IN NUMBER)
BEGIN
  SELECT templastsyncdate INTO vStartDate  FROM f_synctopda WHERE user_id = vUserid AND country_cd = vCountrycode AND servrtable = vServrtable;

  SELECT MAX(SYNC_ID) INTO vnewId FROM F_PDASYNCLOG WHERE COUNTRY_CD = vCountrycode AND USER_ID = vUserid
                                                         AND SERVRTABLE = 'beginTransaction';

  vcurrDate := SYSDATE;

  IF vNoOfRec = 0 THEN
      SELECT lastsyncdate, (vcurrDate - templastsyncdate)*24*60*60 INTO vStartDate1, vduration FROM f_synctopda WHERE user_id = vUserid AND country_cd = vCountrycode AND servrtable = vServrtable;

      vHr := vduration / (60*60);
      vMin := MOD(vHr,1)*60;
      vSec := MOD(vMin,1)*60;

      vTimeDiff := (LPAD(FLOOR(vHr), 2, 0) || ':' || LPAD(FLOOR(vMin), 2, 0) || ':' || LPAD(FLOOR(vSec), 2, 0));

       UPDATE F_PDASYNCLOG SET PDA_START_TIME = JAVA_START_TIME, END_TRANSMIT_TIME = vcurrDate, HQQUERYCOUNT = 0, PDA_END_TIME = vcurrDate
       , SYNC_END_TIME = vcurrDate, COUNT = 0, DURATION = vTimeDiff
       WHERE COUNTRY_CD = vCountrycode AND USER_ID = vUserid AND SQL_START_TIME = vStartDate AND SYNC_ID = vnewId AND SERVRTABLE = vServrtable;
  ELSE
       UPDATE F_PDASYNCLOG SET PDA_START_TIME = JAVA_START_TIME, END_TRANSMIT_TIME = sysdate, HQQUERYCOUNT = vNoOfRec
       WHERE COUNTRY_CD = vCountrycode AND USER_ID = vUserid AND SQL_START_TIME = vStartDate AND SYNC_ID = vnewId AND SERVRTABLE = vServrtable;
  END IF;

  OPEN my_refcur FOR SELECT lastsyncdate,templastsyncdate,user_id,country_cd,servrtable FROM f_synctopda WHERE user_id = vUserid AND country_cd = vCountrycode AND servrtable = vServrtable;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: It seems to me that there is some handler for `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception in the stored procedure which in its turn results in the `Cursor is closed` exception. Can you post the code of the `preNotifySynctopda` SP?

Comment: No, I don't think that is it, I have posted stored procedure to actual question, but there is no exception handler at all.   I can see in their code that it would be easily possible to throw a NO_DATA_FOUND exception from the PL/SQL, and my suspicion remains, that this is being 'swallowed up' by the hibernate/spring framework, which is then returning a non-valid ref-cursor up the stack, hence the Cursor is closed exception.